# Как работает адаптер RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Не могу понять:

1) Adapter -  он заполняет информацией наш ViewHolder?

2) ViewHolder - отображение одного элемента в списке ? И под словом "элемент" подразумевается представление одной строки списка, в которой находятся View-элементы( т.е. есть TextView, ImageView и т.д.) ? Или просто хранит ссылки на view-элементы ?

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Выделено красным  - это ViewHolder? Т.е. один блок в списке ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Адаптер - это некий класс, который отвечает за отображание конкретных данных. Связан с вьюхой RecyclerView. ViewHolder - это некая карточка, один элемент в этом списке. Этот viewHolder связан с xml (вью одного элемента в списке) который хранит в себе TextView и прочие вьюшки.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, добавил картинку, можете ответить пожалуйста

Comment: @Влад да все правильно, это один элемент в списке.